# Passing multiple values in CASE clause

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have 3 set of statuses as follows:

1. Active, In Process
2. Approved, Shipped
3. Closed, Rejected

What I am trying to do is construct a sql query and add a `CASE` clause in the `WHERE`. So far I have the following:

```
DECLARE @showFirstSetOfStatuses BIT = 1
DECLARE @showSecondSetOfStatuses BIT = 0
DECLARE @showThirdSetOfStatuses BIT = 0

SELECT RequestId, RequestName, RequestStatus
FROM SomeTable md
WHERE md.RequestStatus IN(CASE WHEN @showFirstSetOfStatuses = 1 THEN 'Active, In Process' 
                      WHEN @showSecondSetOfStatuses = 1 THEN 'Approved, Shipped' 
                      WHEN @showThirdSetOfStatuses = 1 THEN 'Closed, Rejected' END)
```

This of course does not bring back any result because it's not matching the statuses. I can't seem to figure out how to pass multiple values in the `THEN` part of the `CASE` clause. So something like

```
THEN 'Active', 'In Progress'
...
```

Can someone tell me how to go about this or is it not possible?

Comment: By way of explanation: Your code effectively creates `... WHERE md.RequestStatus IN ( 'Active, In Process' )` which is not the same as `... WHERE md.RequestStatus IN ( 'Active', 'In Process' )`. The second matches either of two strings (`'Active'` or `'In Process'`) while the first will only match the curious string `'Active, In Process'`. A string splitting function could be employed to break the comma delimited list into multiple choices, but Dr. Linoff's answer makes far more sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT RequestId, RequestName, RequestStatus
FROM SomeTable md
WHERE ( (@showFirstSetOfStatuses = 1 AND md.RequestStatus IN ('Active', 'In Process') ) OR
      ( (@showSecondSetOfStatuses = 1 AND md.RequestStatus IN ('Approved', 'Shipped') ) OR 
        (@showThirdSetOfStatuses = 1 AND md.RequestStatus IN ('Closed', 'Rejected') )
      );
```

Food for thought:  I would use one flag that takes on three values, rather than three different flags:

```
DECLARE @showSetOfStatuses INT = 1;

SELECT RequestId, RequestName, RequestStatus
FROM SomeTable md
WHERE ( (@showSetOfStatuses = 1 AND md.RequestStatus IN ('Active', 'In Process') ) OR
      ( (@showSetOfStatuses = 2 AND md.RequestStatus IN ('Approved', 'Shipped') ) OR 
        (@showSetOfStatuses = 3 AND md.RequestStatus IN ('Closed', 'Rejected') )
      );
```

Comment: How would you do this with one flag? Can you provide an example please?

Comment: This does not work as expected. If I change the `@showFirstSetOfStatuses` to 2 it brings back 0 result whereas it should bring back 2 with the statuses `Approved`

Comment: @Code . . . You should fix your question.  It looks silly assigning a value other than 0 or 1 to a `BIT` variable.  That might attract comments.

Comment: My aplogies, I have taken you second suggestion and it's working as expected. Thank you for your help